# Visual Studio Profiling

Tags: c++, profiling

Visual Studio Profiler(using Start Diagnostics without debugging) wont show performance of functions in my own program but functions which I think are more OS related like myProgramName.exe, _scrt_common_main_seh. 
So it does show the performance of the program myProgramName.exe as a whole but doesn't break it down into separate functions of the program as suggested by this site: [Microsoft Guide to profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)

Here's what my Summary looks like and you can see it's not showing the time taken by functions in my program like Merge, Mergesort.

[Call Tree/Hot Path image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzREv.jpg)

How can I look at the performance of functions in my program?

Comment: You may have a data race in your program. This prevents the summary from being constructed properly because racial profiling is prohibited. (Sorry, couldn't resist).

Comment: Polite names may have been stripped out, functions may have been inlined, and compared to your IO costs the rest of the program looks to be pretty insignificant. Take-away: remove the IO from the equation before profiling your algorithm. Or if you are stuck with the IO, see if you can find a way to speed it up.

Comment: Functions in your program probably do not have enough samples associated, so they are not shown in the hot path. Please try another views like "Functions" or "Call Tree" and check whether you can see your functions here. Also please ensure that your sort algorithm runs for enough amount of time (~10 sec or more) so enough number of samples are collected.